# Collabora CODE - .uno:InsertDoc - how to supply file to WOPI client?

Tags: iframe, postmessage, nextcloud, ms-wopi, office-online-server

I am testing CODE 23.05.0.5.

I would like to insert a document into the active editor programatically using the `.uno:InsertDoc` command.

I have created the following function:

```
function sendInsertDoc(name) {
  post({'MessageId': 'Send_UNO_Command',
    'Values': {
      'Command': '.uno:InsertDoc',
      'Args': {
        Name: {
          type: 'string',
          value: `${name}.docx`
        },
        Filter: {
          type: 'string',
          value: ``
        },
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And when I call it, `sendInsertDoc('123')`, I see:

`kit-03405-00023 2023-06-18 16:06:51.956260 +0000 [ kitbroker_12e ] DBG  #17: child_ws: recv [child-617a uno .uno:InsertDoc {"Name":{"type":"string","value":"123.docx"},"Filter":{"type":"string","value":""}} | kit/Kit.cpp:2453`

... in the docker-compose logs, from the WOPI / CODE client.

However there is no mention of an incoming request for the file to the WOPI host ... which I find puzzling.

How to I supply the file to the WOPI client? ... there are no error messages in the console, nothing at all other than the message from `Kit.cpp`.

The example `sendInsertBookMarkUNOCommand()` from here: https://github.com/CollaboraOnline/online/blob/master/browser/html/framed.doc.html#L39 works as expected.

Any ideas please?